# TCPDF generator full html css page

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, tcpdf

i use TCPDF. And i need full page transfer.

https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2016/11/16/bP51.png

my output now looks like this. I dont now where is problém. They need to make the site look exactly how html page (see screen 1)
https://ctrlv.cz/o0dx

I dont no where is problem :-(

```
     data_request('htmlData'); //načti posledne hodnoty
    $style = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/css/styles.css');

    require_once 'TCPDF/tcpdf.php';
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 061');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE . ' 061', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $htmlData = html_entity_decode($htmlData);
    $htmlData .= '<style>' . file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/css/styles.css') . '</style>';
// output the HTML content
    $pdf->writeHTML($htmlData, true, false, true, false, '');

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// reset pointer to the last page
    $pdf->lastPage();


// ---------------------------------------------------------
//Close and output PDF document

    $pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/files/pdf/' . 'ocpdftesting.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: have you checked on TCPDF documentation ?

Comment: On the TCPDF documentation I looked, and there is nothing I could find.

Comment: your problem is the black borders (in your second scrren) right ?

Comment: yes and no. My problem is that it seems mainly a completely different form everything. They need to do a 1 Screen PDF. I pulled the whole html in jQuery and brought him to the TCPDF + loaded style.

Comment: They need to convert the entire page to see one screen at PDF look identical. Using TCPDF

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990216/html-rendering-with-tcpdfphp    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187546/tcpdf-write-after-writehtmlcell-wont-display-nothing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try webkit based PDF generator. There is an API for that: https://pdfapi.io

This creates the identical PDF like you would see the HTML in browser.

Hope that helps.